# Layout widgets in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to layout a `text` and a `button` inside a `row`, such that if the `text` is short, the `text` and the `button` appear next to each other at the center of the `row`(following image).
[image]

As the `text` gets longer, it pushes the `button` to the right. When the `button` reaches at the right edge of the screen, the text should break a line and layout itself in two lines. similar to the image below.
[image]

I have tried this code so far, but the `text` and the `button` are not next to each other.

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                child: Text('Some Text ',
                           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                       ),
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
        ]
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need: https://dartpad.dev/5e28c5273c2c1a41d30bad9f9d11da56?null_safety=true

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        ' the text should break a line and layout itself in two lines. similar to the image below.  the text should break a line and layout itself in two lines. similar to the image below.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ]),
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering how to force the child of `Expanded` widget not to fill the whole available space. Thanks for the `Flexible` widget.